# Cs-Cart pagination in backend orders

Tags: ajax, pagination, cs-cart

Suddenly in CS-Cart, using firefox browser, stopped working AJAX pagination. I have disabled via Dynamic HTML, howerver in backooffice orders menu still not working. Can someone help me ?

When I turn on error reporting I got:

[image: cs-cart errors]

In Chrome webrowser looks like everything is ok

Comment: Anyone know how to fix ?

Comment: What CS-Cart version do you use?

Comment: I'm using CS-Cart: version 3.0.6 ULTIMATE

Comment: We faced similar issue with one of our customers. Hosting provider updated PHP version up to 5.6 which is not supported by CS-Cart 3.0.6

Try to switch PHP version to 5.3 according to the following article:
https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_have_different_php__mysql_versions/

Note: this feature should be supported by the hosting

Answer (score 2):

This is a general issue with older CS-Cart versions (< 4.0, confirmed: 3.0.4, 3.0.5) and new versions of Firefox.

This behavior is not really a "bug" nor a CS-Cart issue per se, but a deprecated feature in Firefox, as certain browsers (like Chrome) do not replicate this behavior.

The issue was isolated in file: `/lib/js/history/jquery.history.js`.

To patch up this issue replace this line:

`return $.browser.mozilla ? hash : decodeURIComponent(hash);`

.. with this line:

`return decodeURIComponent(hash); // <-- patch, patch, ws@da: Poopsilon, Mozilla!`

I hope this solves your problem. Good luck!

*
(Possibly) related bug reports: 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=135309
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=483304
*